# oracle sql count multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I want to count the number of columns that have a certain value in sql.  Example:

```
A B C D E
1 2 1 2 2
```

How can I count that there are 3 columns have the value 2.

Answer (score 6):

You can use decode for this:

```
Select decode(a, 2, 1, 0) 
  + decode(b, 2, 1, 0) 
  + decode(c, 2, 1, 0) 
  + decode(d, 2, 1, 0) 
  + decode(e, 2, 1, 0) 
from my_tab
```

Alternative using case:

```
Select (case a when 2 then 1 else 0 end) 
  + (case b when 2 then 1 else 0 end) 
  + (case c when 2 then 1 else 0 end)  
  + (case d when 2 then 1 else 0 end)  
  + (case e when 2 then 1 else 0 end) 
from my_tab
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to take Frank Schmitt's one step further, you can tuck the "value you want to count" away in an inline table to avoid repeating it:

```
Select
    decode(a, countthis.countvalue, 1, 0) 
  + decode(b, countthis.countvalue, 1, 0) 
  + decode(c, countthis.countvalue, 1, 0) 
  + decode(d, countthis.countvalue, 1, 0) 
  + decode(e, countthis.countvalue, 1, 0) 
from
  my_tab
 ,(select 2 as countvalue from dual) countthis
```